# Disable the visibility options in WP

Tags: post-editor

Is there a way to disable the public vs private vs password-protected visibility UI when editing or quick-editing a post?

A quick scan in the code yields `#visibility`, which I could hide using jQuery, but I was wondering if there was a documented way to do this "properly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick hack to get the job done, in case anyone else needs to do this:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() {
    add_action('admin_head', function() {
        echo <<<EOS
<style type="text/css">
#visibility {
    display: none;
}
</style>

EOS;
    });
});

add_action('restrict_manage_posts', function() {
    echo <<<EOS
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("input[name='keep_private']").parents("div.inline-edit-group:first").hide();
});
</script>

EOS;
});
```

(Still curious to know if there's a better way.)

Comment: I don't see any other *better* way at the moment other than a jQuery hack ;-)

Comment: yes, why jquery is "improper"? unless you want to block it from being processed by the server then I don't see much difference between an HTML generation solution or hiding with JS or CSS

Comment: @MarkKaplun: I was hoping there was a means to disable the functionality altogether, rather than sweep it under the rug.

Comment: @MarkKaplun, because code that shouldn't be seen by the user *shouldn't* be sent from the server at all. Ideally things hidden from the user should be removed in (or by) the PHP, and not "kinda hidden" by CSS or JS in the browser. Not only is it cleaner, but in some cases there are security reasons for wanting to prevent options from being sent/read by the server.

Comment: @thirdender, yes you probably have in your CSS and JS files only code that is applied only on the specific page it is loaded for and nothing more, no comments in the HTML and no spaces .... On this site we usually have a practical approach to programming and, not a religious ones, unless it is a truly horrible practice. With the way wordpress code in this area is structured, jQuery solution is the cleanest and more maintainable approach, when it is compared to buffering and filtering the HTML.when it is generated. You will not get a A+ grade for this code but in the real world it is better

Comment: There's always going to be a tension between doing things quick and doing things right. That doesn't mean you *shouldn't* try to do things the right way. To follow your example, you *should* comment your code, and you *should* indent code properly. Maybe you don't have time, but that doesn't mean it should be something you *avoid*… you just might not be able to do it *this* project. I believe as programmers we should always strive to find the *best* way to do things. Just because a hackish way to do something exists doesn't mean we should stop trying our best. `</rant>` :-p

Comment: And for this particular issue, I checked the code and I don't see any way to remove this aside from the CSS/JS hack, or as @MarkKaplun mentioned using output buffering. The quick edit form is generated in `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php`, and it doesn't look like there are any real conditionals that will affect whether or not the privacy options appear (except a bulk edit conditional, but that won't affect quick edit afaik). In my opinion this is a failing of WordPress and PHP, but such is life. If there becomes a demand, support for this feature may materialize. C'est la vie.